# Unable to import name 'create_connection' from 'sql'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, python-module, python-sql

I am trying to use Flask on my pc but I keep getting an error whenever I import from the sql module. The error states:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'create_connection' from 'sql' (C:<Directory to sql.py>)

```
# Imports
import flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from sql import create_connection
from sql import execute_read_query
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.  The code in sql.py may also be needed if it is code that you wrote.  If it's from a third-party package please provide a link to its project homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the file path problem or package install issue. If you confirm your project path don't have the same file named "sql.py", you can try to below command:

```
pip uninstall python-sql
```

then

```
pip install python-sql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).